# indicator function with integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, upper-lower-bounds

I have a following integral

$$\int_{0}^{T-b}f\left(\tau\right)d\tau$$

where $T-b$ is an arbitrary constant number. I try to change the limits of this integral by using an indicator function and I write

$$\int_{0}^{n}f\left(\tau\right)d\tau\boldsymbol{1}_{\tau\leq T-b}$$

where $n$ is an arbitrary value. I am not sure if it is a correct way to write the integral in this way. And also, I am trying to use the fundamental theorem of calculus as

$$f\left(n\right)\boldsymbol{1}_{n\leq T-b}$$

Am I allowed to do these operations? If not, how can I correct my mistakes?

Comment: Judging from the questions you've asked over the past little while, you seem to be studying economics but without a good grasp of real analysis. I recommend reading through *Principles of Real Analysis* by Rudin and doing as many of the exercises as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. Yes, you are right. I should work on it.

Comment: +1 to your comment. I think I misunderstood your original question, so I updated my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f$ be a continuous real-valued map. Letting $x=T-b$, your integral is
$$
\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt=\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t)\boldsymbol{1}_{(-\infty,x]}(t)dt.
$$
If I understand your question correctly, you are interested in the derivative of the function $F:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined
by
$$
F(y)=\int_{0}^{y}f(t)\boldsymbol{1}_{(-\infty,x]}(t)dt.
$$
By the fundamental theorem of calculus,
$$
F^{\prime}(y)=f(y)\boldsymbol{1}_{(-\infty,x]}(y)\qquad\text{if }y\neq x.
$$
The proof of the fundamental theorem uses the mean-value theorem and as such, it requires the continuity of the integrand. Therefore, the above only holds at $y\neq x$.